# What's the maximum amount of data extension I can bulk-upsert via REST Api?

Tags: rest-api, dataextensions, marketing-cloud

I am using the REST Api (POST /dataevents/key:{key}/rowset)
https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/hub/data-events/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.html

in order to update/insert(upsert) a bulk of data extension to sfmc via REST api call.

And we want to be able to upload maybe upto 10k rows at a time per day. We also want it to be able to grab upto 9GB of data if possible -- as a one time job.
Currently, upto 4698 records (less than 1GB)succeeds, and it fails with the http status code 500 (internal server error) beyond that.

1. What's the default max amount of data (MB/GB) that I can send via this api - and how come is it throwing an error with such small amount of data
2. Is there a way to change the max so that it can process upto 10k rows at a time.

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  X-Mashery-Responder: 01-05
  Vary: Origin
  X-Mashery-Message-ID: fb716c5f-27e9-4a47-9e32-e9fbcf782d86
  Connection: close
  Date: Wed, 23 Mar 2016 19:16:42 GMT
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Content-Length: 117
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
}

Comment: Upto 4698 records it returns code 200. It just fails on sfmc side with the code 500 to process any more data than that.

Comment: Could you get an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is max 50 records for synchronous calls, and 100 records for asynchronous calls. But no real limits have been defined by Salesforce.